# Creating a RDF file using a txt file as input

Tags: python, parsing, rdf, text-files

How can I convert a simple tab-delimited txt file (containing the headers subject, predicate, object) into a RDF N-triple format using the python module RDFlib?

Answer (score 10):

It's not very complicated. First, some necessary imports:

```
from StringIO import StringIO
from rdflib import Graph, URIRef
```

I'm using `StringIO` here to avoid creating a file. Instead, I'll just list some contents and a file-like object with these contents:

```
contents = '''\
subject1\tpredicate1\tobject1
subject2\tpredicate2\tobject2'''  
tabfile = StringIO(contents)
```

Then create a graph and load all triples to it:

```
graph = rdflib.Graph()

for line in tabfile:
    triple = line.split()                # triple is now a list of 3 strings
    triple = (URIRef(t) for t in triple) # we have to wrap them in URIRef
    graph.add(triple)                    # and add to the graph
```

Now you have the whole graph in memory (assuming you have enough memory, of course). You can now print it:

```
print graph.serialize(format='nt')

# prints:
# <subject1> <predicate1> <object1> .
# <subject2> <predicate2> <object2> .
```

Comment: Nitpick: you're serializing the graph in N3 format. Since the original poster asked for N-Triples, I just thought I'd point out that those two formats are not the same.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra: Thanks, I didn't read the post carefully enough. I'll correct my answer.